# Custom Error Message in Script Crash? PHP

Tags: php, die

I've never worked with advanced error handling, and I can't find an obvious answer searching.

In the scope a script (`require_once`) how do you set up a custom "die" message?

Generally my users see the page-load die with no response. I'd like to direct them to a help file regarding memory so they absolutely cannot miss the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill a script and output a message using the die() command

```
die("Your message here");
```

You can also throw custom exceptions in PHP 5+, and catch them and at that point output a message to the users.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` automatically stops execution if it fails.

Try e.g. `(include_once file.php) or header('Location: http://.../path/to/help');`, or

```
if(!(include_once file.php)) {
    // redirect?
}
```